# Bash environment variables not setting

Tags: linux, aws

I am trying to configure the AWS CLI using a bash script. I have the below in my script and it will not set the values. When I echo out the variables names it just shows a blank line.

**script code**

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key>

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret_key>

export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region>
```

Comment: how are you trying to print the variables ... contents (not names)? After/outside the script, or within the script?

Comment: You have to source the script instead of running it.

Comment: I am trying to echo out the variables because they are not working. I these values are to be used by the AWS cli program. I am testing the echo outside the script once it has ran.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro What do you mean?

Comment: `source script.sh` or `. script.sh`  instead of `script.sh`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro the above scipt code is part of script not the whole thing, also what would I need to change if I put just the above into a script and included that in my main one?

Comment: @JoshKirby, please [edit] your question to include a complete example of a script that exhibits the issue, along with a sample of how you run the script. `sh -c 'export ID=foo; echo "$ID"'` should work with whatever `sh` you have, so there's not enough information here to tell what the issue is.

Comment: @JoshKirby, I will expand Rui answer: the way how you execute your script matters. If you execute like this: `./script.sh` - new shell process will be spawned, and when script terminates all is gone - variables will not persist in your current shell environment. If you execute via `source script.sh`, the script will run in a current shell process, thus all the environment changes will remain after script stops it's execution.

Answer (score 0):

> **Superuser**: [what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it](https://superuser.com/a/176788/596917)
>
> Short answer: sourcing will run the commands in the current shell process. executing will run the commands in a new shell process.

More info in the original [question/answer](https://superuser.com/a/176788/596917)

The below example shows the difference between running the script and `source`ing it:

```
$ cat a.sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=key
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_key
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=region
$ ./a.sh 
$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

$ source a.sh 
$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
key
$
```